# If $|G|=154$, and it not a direct product, then it must be isomorphic to $D_{154}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Suppose $|G|=154$ and $G$ is not decomposable in the sense that there are no proper subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ such that $G \cong H \times K$. Show that $G \cong D_{154}$.

Here is my attempt: Let $P \in \mathrm{Syl}_{7}(G)$ and $Q \in \mathrm{Syl}_{11}(G)$. Using Sylow theory we can show that that at least one $P$ or $Q$ is normal in $G$, which implies that $N=PQ \le G$. In fact $[G\colon N]=2$ so $N \trianglelefteq G$.

Let $H \in \mathrm{Syl}_{2}(G)$. We have $HN \le G$ and $|HN|=|H||N|=|G|$ because $|H \cap N|=1$ (since the only element with order dividing both $77, 2$ is $e$). Hence $G = HN$.

To see that $G \cong N \rtimes H$, we need $\varphi \in \mathrm{Hom}(H, \mathrm{Aut}(N))$ that is non-trivial. We have
\begin{align*}
 \varphi\colon H &\to  \mathrm{Aut}(N)\\
 h &\mapsto \varphi_{h}\colon n \mapsto hnh^{-1};
\end{align*}
If $h \neq e$ then $|h|=2$. We always have $|\varphi_{h}| \mid |h|$. To form a non-trivial semi-direct product we need a $\varphi_{h} \in \mathrm{Aut}(H)$ with order $2$.

The proof would be done if I could prove that we must have $\varphi_{h}\colon n \mapsto hnh^{-1}=n^{-1}$ and then $G \cong \langle n, h \mid n^{77}=h^{2}=e, hnh^{-1}=n^{-1} \rangle = D_{154}$.

Question: How can I show that inversion is the only possible automorphism of order $2$?

Comment: The equation $x^2\equiv1\pmod{77}$ has four pairwise incongruent solution.  Says the Chinese remainder theorem. They are $\pm1$ and $\pm34$. On the group the resulting semidirect products correspond to $C_{154}$, $D_{77}$, $D_{11}\times C_7$ and $D_7\times C_{11}.$ All according to whether an element of order two centralizes both, one of, or neither of $P$ and $Q$ (but not in that order).

Comment: Oh, and you seem to be using a source that uses the order of the group as a subscript of $D$ when denoting a dihedral group. I stick to the notation where $D_n$ stands for the group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon, so for me $|D_n|=2n$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I'm sorry, but can you please say some more because I'm not quite sure if I understand your first comment. Also, sorry for the notation. My definition of $D_{154}$ is near the end of the question.

Comment: What my comment amounts to is that the other choices for $\phi_h$ lead to groups that decompose as direct products. The connection to my first comment is that necessarily $\phi_h(n)=n^x$ for some $x$ determined modulo $77$. As $h$ has order two, we must have $\phi_h(\phi_h(n))=n^{x^2}=n$, so $x^2\equiv1\pmod{77}$.

Comment: In other words, the answer to the question in your last sentence is that you cannot show that because that claim is not true. However, the other possibilities lead to direct products of proper subgroups.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Understood. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, both $P$ and $Q$ are normal, because by Sylow theorems, $n_{11} \mid 14$ and $11\mid (n_{11}-1)$. So we get that $n_{11}=1$. Same discussion for $n_{7}$. Now by normalizer-centralizer (or any otherway), we see that $|G:C(Q)|= 1$ or $2$. If $|G:C(Q)|= 1$, $G\cong Q\times K$ (we know that such $K$ exists), a contradiction. So $|G:C(Q)|= 2$. Note that  since $G\cong (Q\times P)\rtimes H$, we just need to prove that $H$ acts Frobeniusly on $P$, since we know that it acts Frobeniusly on $Q$. Again $|G:C(P)|= 1$ or $2$, and if $|G:C(P)|= 1$, $G\cong P\times K$ (we know that such $K$ exists), a contradiction. Hence $|G:C(P)|= 2$, which means $H$ acts Frobeniusly on $P$. Now we conclude that $H$ acts Freobeniusly on $N$, and that means $G\cong D_{154}$.